# Not able to use wild cards in tab filters

Tags: discussion, bug, tags, wildcard

It is possible to use wild cards in favorite and ignored tags as shown below, which I find to be a very useful feature.

> [image]

---

But it's not possible to do the same in a tab:

> [image]

If I click the "save" in the above scenario, it just clears the text and no tag filter is added (If we select a tag and then clear it, the save button stays active, it's a bug with respect to current behavior).

---

I consider this as a bug because this is inconsistent with existing behavior. I expect to be able to save the wild card just like favorite or ignored tags.
This is especially useful in case of tags like `jquery-ui` because there are 20+ `jquery-ui-*` tags. Some of them can be burned, merged or new ones can be added as time goes by and I'd like to be able to see them in one tab instead of manually adding and removing those many tags, Just like what I get if I click on the wild card in favorite tags

Comment: Nav 2.0 no longer exists. Voting to close as no repro